# How does optimize.newton choose x1 if fprime is not provided and it must use the secant method?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, newtons-method

The `scipy.optimize.newton` documentation reads: "The Newton-Raphson method is used if the derivative fprime of func is provided, otherwise the secant method is used." The secant method requires two estimates of the zero of func, x0 and x1. But the examples provided show that `optimize.newton` works with the secant method when ONLY x0 is input. So I assume `optimize.newton` is somehow  assigning x1 based off our input of x0, but I'm not sure and am curious to know what's going on. Any clarification would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: a perturbed version of `x0` is used.

It looks like the actual behavior should be documented better.  The source code for the function starts at [this line in the file `zeros.py`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/a6124626bb99d73aa7f99bf8e3da7d9e2c670aa8/scipy/optimize/zeros.py#L94); the code relevant to your question is:

```
        # Secant method
        if x1 is not None:
            if x1 == x0:
                raise ValueError("x1 and x0 must be different")
            p1 = x1
        else:
            eps = 1e-4
            p1 = x0 * (1 + eps)
            p1 += (eps if p1 >= 0 else -eps)
```

`p1` is the actual value that will be used in the subsequent code as the second point.  So if `x1` is None, `p1` is set to a slightly modified version of `x0`.

(See [this github issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10103) for a discussion of that calculation.)

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing things up for me and taking the time to respond. I really do appreciate it!